# How can this PHP code be changed to allow for random download link generation?

Tags: php

This HTML form and PHP allows a user to upload a file, but what should I add to the PHP to generate a unique link to a page where users can download this file (similar idea to megaupload)?

HTML:

```
<form action="gogogo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label class="filebutton" for="file">Upload </label> 
  <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file" onChange="form.submit()"> <br />

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Configuration - Your Options
  $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png', '.txt'); 
  $max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
  $upload_path = 'files/'; 
  $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; 
  $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); 

  // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
  if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
    die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

  // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
  if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
    die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

  // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
  if(!is_writable($upload_path))
    die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

  // Upload the file to your specified path.
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
     echo 'Success';
  else
     echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.'; 
?>
```

Comment: What goes wrong? What does your code currently do? What should it do? Why does it not work?

Comment: At the moment the code just allows the user to select a file and upload it, and the file is the stored in my uploads folder. I want the code to also generate a unique link to a page to download the file that the user has just uploaded, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like dynamic links to the user uploaded content, you probably want to store meta data about the uploaded file to your database and use something like a primary key to uniquely identify each upload. That way the lookup can be done on the primary key when the user supplies a link to later download that file.

For example, one simple way to go about about this is to create a `upload` table in your database with the following schema...

```
CREATE TABLE upload (
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    filename varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
    path varchar(500) NOT NULL,
)
```

Now when the upload happens you can do something like the following in your PHP code to insert the record into your database...

```
const MY_UPLOAD_PATH = '/path/to/uploaded/files';
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO upload VALUES(null, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array($_FILES['userfile']['name'], MY_UPLOAD_PATH));
$fileId = $db->lastInsertId();

$fileLink = "/download.php?id=$fileId";

echo "<a href='$fileLink'>Download your file!</a>";
```

Then you can write a `download.php` script that does the look up on the `upload` table based on `id` and you have a way to locate the file!

If you want to do temporarily generated links for downloads (*that expire after a while, for example*) you can just create another table in your database with a unique token like [uniqid](http://php.net/uniqid) or similar, and link it with the primary id key in the `upload` table. Just make sure you add a time stamp so you know if it's expired or not. Then you can do the look up in `download.php` on the other table instead and use a `JOIN` statement.

Example...

```
SELECT filename, path FROM upload JOIN tmp ON tmp.fileId = upload.id WHERE (NOW() - tmp.ts) <= 3600 -- expires after 1 hour from insertion
```

Comment: How is `varchar(500)` going to work? Varchar is max 255 right?

Comment: @Koen. Not necessarily, no. In MySQL, for example, the limit of `Varchar` is 65,535 bytes per row.

Comment: Oh well, docs knows it all; "Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions".

Comment: @Koen. Right, I highly doubt anyone is still using MySQL < 5.0.3 today, let alone the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need the DB structure to take care of the links, then you need to generate a random ID, you can use something like
`substr(md5(rand()),0,8);`
which will generate a random string which you can use for identifying where the file is stored according to a path stored on the DB.

EDIT: 
By handling the links I mean something like for example you store the ID as a column named fileid and store the path in another column, like for example /path/to/upload.php. 
When the ID is retrieved, get the path corresponding to that ID and place it: `<a href="<?php echo $filepath; ?>">`

Then you can get it random. Retrieve the ID by using a $_GET query:
`http://yourfilehost.com/get.php?fileid=fileid goes here`

EDIT2:
Before choosing a random string and putting it into the database make sure it is unique, as a member stated, random != unique.

EDIT3:

```
<?php


// Simple example, no security whatsoever.

// retrive GET filepath

$fileid = $_GET['fileid'];

// do some queries to check if it is unique

if ($unique) {
    // retrieve path from database
    $filepath = /* retrieve path from database corresponding to ID */;
    $filename = /*retrieve filename from database corresponding to ID */;
    echo "<a href=\"$filepath\">$filename</a>";
}
```

Comment: Be careful. Random != Unique. You want unique identifiers because you don't want to accidentally generate the same identifier for two different files, lest you allow someone to download the wrong file.

Comment: Definitely might want to check in the DB if identifier already exists, thank you for adding that.

Comment: Thank you very much! Still unsure as to what exactly i'd put in download.php though

Comment: I'll add some more info in like 5 minutes :)

Comment: Done, added example :)